# reading list of files in R

Tags: r, filelist

In R, I am trying to process multiple files using a loop. A file contains paths of many other files that contain data for computation. Can somebody tell me the simple script to do it?

list.txt:

```
/data/tmp/b.dat
/data/tmp/c.dat
/data/tmp/d.dat
```

inside b.dat:

```
1 15.30 20.30 15.0
2 7.3 5.0 2.0
...
n 5.0 2.0 6.0
```

In the meantime, data is processed for each row. How can the data be transposed?

Comment: Could you please include a sample of your code? People will be more willing to help if you show that you've already tried to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a one-liner:

```
lapply(scan("list.txt",""), read.table,sep=" ", row.names=1)
```

A short explanation: `scan("list.txt","")` scans your file containing the list of locations (space separated)and outputs them as a vector of characters (because of the `""`) then with `lapply` you apply to each of those locations the function `read.table` with the right separator and other needed arguments. The final output is a list of datasets.